# Power Bi Api - Service principal authentication is not supported

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-api

I am trying to pull data for all Power Bi Apps in our organization using a Function App.

I am reading the documentation for Power BI APi:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/apps/getreport

Though I dont really understand that it states:

**Required scope: Report.ReadWrite.All or Report.Read.All
To set the permissions scope, see Register an app.**

When at the same time it says:

**"Limitations: Service principal authentication is not supported."**

I would really like to use a service principal. :/

Comment: Is your report shared in an app? Is is important you get the report from the App in the API or is it ok if you get the report in a workspace? What are you trying to accomplish with this API call?

Comment: @SirLanceLang, any luck with this? What did you end up doing for this issue?